# Marking old "useful command line commands" question as historical

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Does anyone else think its worthwhile locking [Useful Command-line Commands on Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-command-line-commands-on-windows) as historical significance only?

I know its community wiki but its still a time sink, and is the sort of question that would get closed these days.

Not only that, but as time goes by, its going to become an overly large and unusable list of every vague command that everyone can remember and lose whatever usefulness it had when it becomes impossible to find what you're looking for in the answers unless you're prepared to sit there and plough through page after page. Someone appears to have added the shortcut names to every control panel applet they can remember. How *useful* and relevant is that to serverfault, really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been locked and is being retained for historical significance.